# latexdiff produces invalid output from changes to \multirow

Tags: errors, changes, latexdiff

A co-worker and I are hoping to start using latexdiff for tracking changes in a document he is writing and I am proofreading. I've run into a spot where latexdiff seems to be generating invalid output. Here is the original text (which is inside a `\begin{tabular}` block):

```
\multirow{1}*{4. Conclude}
            & a. Write report                   & Joel/12hrs            & \hspace{10mm} 9/20 \\\hline
```

Here is the changed text:

```
\multirow{2}*{4. Conclude Project}
            & a. Write report                   & Joel/12hrs            & \hspace{10mm} 9/20 \\\cline{2-4}
            & b. Debrief                        & Joel/1hr              & \hspace{10mm} 9/21 \\\hline
```

Here is the output from latexdiff:

```
\DIFdelbegin %DIFDELCMD < \multirow{1}%%%
\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \multirow{2}\DIFaddend *{4. Conclude \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{Project}\DIFaddend }
            & a. Write report                   & Joel/12hrs            & \hspace{10mm} 9/20 \\\DIFaddbegin \cline{2-4}
            & \DIFadd{b. Debrief                        }& \DIFadd{Joel/1hr                 }& \DIFadd{\hspace{10mm} 9/21 }\\\DIFaddend \hline
```

and here are the last few lines of the console:

```
[]\OT1/cmss/bx/n/12 Milesestones and Re-quired Tasks: Pro-posed Start-ing Date 
|   [] 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \let 
l.464 ...end \DIFaddbegin \multirow{2}\DIFaddend *
                                                  {4. Conclude \DIFaddbegin ...
```

I'm too much of a LaTeX neophyte to interpret this error. Is there something we can do either in the original files or in latexdiff's output to resolve this error?

Comment: never used that tool but it is putting the markup _in the middle_ of multirows arguments which is bad, it looks like you omitted the braces from the `*` argument which might have confused it, try `{*}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. That solved the problem. Please post as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a position of total ignorance, apparently this works:-)

Never used that tool but it is putting the markup in the middle of multirows arguments which is bad, it looks like you omitted the braces from the `*` argument which might have confused it, try `{*}`

Comment: The docs for latexdiff state that well-formed input should result in well-formed output. So making the input well-formed is an excellent first step. I'm still getting past the basics of LaTeX so I didn't recognize that the asterisk outside the braces was a problem.