# How do I use multirow in LaTeX?

Tags: tables, formatting, multirow

How do I code a table to look like this? I'm not the best at LaTeX and can't seem to wrap my head around `\multirow`. I checked other examples prior to posting but they used `\multicolumn` and it just confused me even more.

[image: Table]

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c|c|} 
 \hline
 TextA & TextB & TextC & TextD & TextE\\
 \hline
 A & TextF & TextG & TextH & TextI\\
 B & TextJ & TextK & TextL & TextM\\
 C & \multirow{2}*{TextF} & TextG & TextH & TextI\\
 \cline{3-3}
 & TextJ & TextK \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

I was trying something like this.. I'm starting to have problems as I'm trying to multirow within a multirow? I'm not sure of the process here. I would like TextG to be split into 2 and TextH and TextI to be the cells which are split in 3 but not sure how to go about it.
Will then TextJ and TextK be the contents of the split TextG cell?

Comment: what you try so far? from images i see, that `multirow` cells you need only in the bottom row: `\multirow{3}*{....}` in the first two columns, and `\multirow{2}*{....}` in the third column. 
 for use `multirow` you need to load `multirow` package in document preamble. for more, you should provide small but complete document with this tale (without multi row cells).

Comment: @Zarko thanks for the response. I'm mainly confused by what the  brackets mean after multirow, and where to insert the text that you want in those rows. How do I split them into threes? Is that not the name of the multirow for the previous one?

Comment: dots in `\multirow{3}*{....}` are instead real text (which is unknown to us). please provide small document which produce showed table. and don't bother with `multirow` this we can easily add to table.  help us to help you. writing document from scratch and don't knowing more about your table doesn't lead to desired result.

Comment: @Zarko I've edited the post to add a somewhat attempt at this.

Comment: Unrelated, but you may  use some visual latex table generator (like https://www.tablesgenerator.com/#).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[image]

i extend your table code (and also correct it) that the table mimic the table which you show in question. note: cells in rows, where `multirow` cell is placed, had to be presented but should be empty (see mwe below):

mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
 \hline
 Text A     & Text B    & Text C    & Text D    & Text E    \\
 \hline
 A          & Text F    & Text G    & Text H    & Text I    \\
 \hline
 B          & Text J    & Text K    & Text L    & Text M    \\
 \hline
 \multirow{3}*{Text N}
            & \multirow{3}*{Text O}
                        & Text P    & Text Q    & Text R    \\
 \cline{3-5}
            &           & \multirow{2}*{Text S}
                                    & Text T    & Text U    \\
 \cline{4-5}
            &           &           & Text V    & Text Z    \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! What does the \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3} do? Also can you explain why you used multirow on text N and why its width is 3?

Comment: (i) basic knowledge about table settings you can learn on site https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables.; (ii)  `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3} ` stretch distance between  table rows. default is 1, so 1.3 increase distance about 30% (good to know that in multi line cells doesn't work well in all circumstances); (ii) in `\multirow{3}{*{...}` number `3` tel, hove many lines of text in other columns cell will span. cell with `Text N` span 3 lines of text (which in this case is equal to 3 table rows. the same valid for cell which contain `Text =`, bit cell with `Text S` span only 2 lines/rows.

Comment: the last sentence in my above comment has some typing/spelling errors. it should be: *the same applies to a cell containing a `Text O`. cell with `Text S` span only 2 lines/rows*.

Answer (score 4):

You can do such table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

In `{NiceTabular}`, you merge cells both horizontally and vertically with the command `\Block`. For the rows, you give the number of *logical* rows (and not the number of physical lines as with `\multicolumn`).

With the key `hvlines`, all the rules are drawn, excepted in the blocks (constructed by `\Block`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc}[hvlines]
 Text A     & Text B    & Text C    & Text D    & Text E    \\
 A          & Text F    & Text G    & Text H    & Text I    \\
 B          & Text J    & Text K    & Text L    & Text M    \\
 \Block{3-1}{Text N}
            & \Block{3-1}{Text O}
                        & Text P    & Text Q    & Text R    \\
            &           & \Block{2-1}{Text S}
                                    & Text T    & Text U    \\
            &           &           & Text V    & Text Z    \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick comment that you should always provide the central brackets in multirow. ie, from the example above:

```
\multirow{3}*{Text N}
```

Should actually be:

```
\multirow{3}{*}{Text N}
```

This is because the lack of `{*}` brackets will break `latexdiff`, see for instance: [latexdiff produces invalid output from changes to \multirow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64441/latexdiff-produces-invalid-output-from-changes-to-multirow)